PTX equivalent for "nextafter" (FP16)?
Hacking on numba, I am trying to find the PTX-equivalent of nextafter. The official PTX documentation does not include one specific instruction, as far as I can tell (though I could be overlooking it), so I assume this has to be implemented "manually" (in PTX code).

Is nextafter part of the PTX instruction set?
If not, is there an implementation out there in the wild (before I reinvent the wheel)?
If both latter options ain't it, any idea on how to approach this?

EDIT numba specifically implements operators for FP16 in PTX and calls standard library functions otherwise. This is what I am looking for.

what prevents you to directly using the nextafter C function?

@AbatorAbetor Trying to fix a gap in numba's CUDA compiler pipeline similar to e.g. floor.

You can see the ptx implementation for example on godbolt when using nextafter https://godbolt.org/z/ddos5srG7

also e.g. this, but @AbatorAbetor has covered it nicely

@AbatorAbetor I am slowly understanding why numba is using PTX assembly: It's specifically for FP16 implementations of those functions.

it should be possible to use the FP32 PTX implementation as exposed by @AbatorAbetor as a roadmap to create a PTX FP16 version.  Use 16 bit data loads and movement, a 16 bit abs function, 16 bit add, etc. etc.  In fact most of this should exist as available 16-bit intrinsics, so you could probably string together a CUDA C++/intrinsic version, and then look at the resultant generated PTX code.

This may also be of interest as another possible "roadmap": convert a FP32 code to a FP16 code, then look at the generated PTX.
